Логика ЛС в discord.py
Пишу бота на discord.py. Допустим у меня есть пользователь(условно админ) которому должно отправляться сообщение при вводе slash команды. Вот мой код:
@tree.command(name = 'test', description="test")
async def test(interaction):
    pass #Тут должно отправляться сообщение админу в ЛС

Подскажите пожалуйста! Буду рад любой помощи!
